# Its horizon was firmly international

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a question about the meaning of the adverb "*firmly*" in [this article](http://www.versobooks.com/blogs/1137-eric-hobsbawm-s-introduction-to-the-2012-edition-of-marx-amp-engels-the-communist-manifesto):

> This small pamphlet is by far the most influential single piece of political writing since the French Revolutionary Declaration of the Rights of Man and Citizen. By good luck it hit the streets only a week or two before the outbreak of the revolutions of 1848, which spread like a forest fire from Paris across the continent of Europe. Although its horizon was ***firmly*** international – the first edition hopefully, but wrongly, announced the impending publication of the Manifesto in English, French, Italian, Flemish and Danish – its initial impact was exclusively German.

I already checked dictionaries, but I cannot find a definition of "*firmly*" that fits the usage above.  What do others think?

Comment: "Without doubt"

Comment: @V.V. Is there a dictionary definition?

Comment: www.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: An adverb constructed from *ADJ* + *-ly* ordinarily derives its sense from *ADJ*. Compare [Collins s.v. 'firm'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/firm), senses 3 and 5. I vote to close this as a dictionary question.

Answer (score 1):

Elliptical writing.

The problem is "horizon" which refers, obliquely, to the future intentions of the *authors* of the pamphlet, that is, what they saw "ahead" in the distance.

They were firm in their resolve to see that it went international, having plans for translations into different languages.

Comment: So, it was poorly written?

Comment: You would not have been thrown off the track had the author of the article written "Although the authors of the manifesto intended it to reach an international audience  – the first edition announcing translations into English, French, Italian, Flemish and Danish – its initial impact was exclusively German."   The reader must understand how the word "horizon" was being used in order to understand the elliptical phrase "firmly international". To the extent that the article's author is relying upon the reader's familiarity with that elliptical style, he is not being firmly international.

Answer (score 1):

> Although its horizon was firmly international

means *Although its range was without doubt international*

The source was mentioned in my comments.

Comment: So, it was poorly written?